# multiscreen/dualscreen on linux freerdp

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors

my laptop got two displays, 0(default), and 1(addon 12" display).
When I run xfreerdp, I can choose which monitor I want to use.

```
xfreerdp /monitors:0 /multimon /v:192.168.1.2
```

start freerdp on display 0,

```
xfreerdp /monitors:1 /multimon /v:192.168.1.2
```

start freerdp on display 1

But, when I want to use xfreerdp on both screens (as the remote linux got also dual screen)
it only shows it up on the screen 0 and not also on screen 1

```
xfreerdp /monitors:0,1 /multimon /v:192.168.1.2
```

Why is this, am I doing something wrong?